# uncaught typeError intermediate value is not a function , when using BlueBird.Promisify

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I try to Promisify elasticsearch.client.index, and I get
Uncaught typeerror intermediate value is not a function
at makeNodePromissifedEval

I use blubebird 3.5.0
nodejs 8.1.2

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

This error sometimes happen when you're not using semicolons.

Since you didn't include your code it's impossible to tell if that's the case but 95% when people ask about this error they're missing semicolons.

Example:

```
// missing semicolons:
const x = 10
(x => console.log(x))(20)
// TypeError: 10 is not a function

// semicolons present:
const x = 10;
(x => console.log(x))(20);
// works fine
```